# C abbreviated array naming

Tags: c, arrays

I am working with PLC's and as an exercise I am writing a little PLC program in C to help me better understand C, PLC's and translation of ladder logic to C.

The PLC I am working with has a fixed memory space and variables are stored in "V memory" locations. e.g. I store a temperature value of 31 in a memory location called V3700. So any time I need to manipulate the temperature I use V3700 in the program. To emulate the PLC memory space I am simply using an array called Vmem[65536].

The PLC uses octal addressing. So in my above example, V3700 is in octal so it is actually 0x7C0 or 1984 (decimal).

What I would like to do is simplify writing `Vmem[x]` so I don't have to use brackets. e.g.:

```
//current method to store 31 to V3700
Vmem[3700] = 31;

//How I want to address the array
V3700 = 31;

//Another example
if(V3700 > 5) printf("V3700 is greater than 5.\n");
```

Is there any way I can abbreviate the array name and the address? Even if the octal part is too much and decimal values are all that will work I am okay with that. And I know I can #define

I am developing using Ubuntu 12.04 and GCC 4.6.3.

Comment: If you're going to assign a symbolic name to something, don't make that name the memory location.  The name should be the semantic meaning of what's at the memory location.  `#define TEMPERATURE Vmem[03700]`, or `#define TEMPERATURE_OFFSET 03700` ... `Vmem[TEMPERATURE_OFFSET] = 31`.  You'll want to do this if you ever have the desire to read your program without cross referencing the data sheet every line...  I mean, you wouldn't `#define ONE 1` would you?

Comment: I realize naming variables according to their function is more realistic but I am sticking with the naming convention the PLC uses. Though, to be fair the PLC code editor supports tagging memory and other variables with user defined names names to keep things sane.

Answer (score 6):

There is no simpler way than

```
#define V3700 (Vmem[3700])
```

If you have lots of these cases you could write a program that generates a header containing all the define statements, to save you typing it all out.

Comment: Be sure it's really worth it, and confine those macros to the smallest section possible to avoid inadvertently re-writing other code.

Comment: I was hoping there was a macro that could change the naming of variables. BUT it appears I would have to generate a header with an entry for each address. And Deduplicator brought up a good point, I have to make sure it doesn't clobber any other code.